# convert two 1D arrays to set of tuples

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose that we have the following arrays

```
a = np.asarray([1,2,3])
b = np.asarray([4,5,6])
```

How can we turn `a` and `b` into the following array `c` containing tuples?

```
c = [(1,4),(2,5),(3,6)]
```

Comment: this is exactly what the builtin `zip` function does

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`zip` combines 2 lists into a list of tuples pretty simply.

```
c = zip(a,b)
```